# Finding Parent-Child relationship where levels can be repeated

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a scenario (in SQL Server 2012) whereby I have to determine the parent-child relationship between extensions on a given day. I've managed to get the data into a format that can identify a master record (i.e. Start CallerID and nextCallerID (transfer)), sub records and end record (i.e. ending CallID). See table below.

The problem is that any CallID or NextCallID can be repeated later the same day as a Master, Sub or End call. I basically have to find the correct group of calls and the Master CallID has to be repeated per group. Also, a call can be transferred many times which means it can have many Sub records.

Data:

```
Timestamp               | CallID      | NextCallID  | Type
------------------------|-------------|-------------|-----
2017-07-26 14:37:24.000 | 37468024    | 37594497    | M
2017-07-26 14:51:27.000 | 37594497    | 37595080    | S
2017-07-26 14:59:30.000 | 37595080    | 37512345    | S
2017-07-26 14:59:59.000 | 37512345    | NULL        | E
2017-07-26 18:59:59.000 | 37594497    | NULL        | M
```

Desired Result:

```
Timestamp               | MasterCallID | CallID    | NextCallID | Type
------------------------|------------- |-----------|------------|-------
2017-07-26 14:37:24.000 | 37468024     | 37468024  | 37594497   | Master
2017-07-26 14:51:27.000 | 37468024     | 37594497  | 37595080   | Sub/transfer
2017-07-26 14:59:30.000 | 37468024     | 37595080  | 37512345   | Sub/transfer
2017-07-26 14:59:59.000 | 37468024     | 37512345  | NULL       | End Call
2017-07-26 18:59:59.000 | 37594497     | 37594497  | NULL       | Master
```

As you can see from the the data set above, CallID 37594497 was a child to a master record and then later in the day was a Master of a new record/call.

Apologies if the problem statement/table format is unclear.
Any assistance in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Amendment:**

The proposed solutions does not work with the following scenario:

Data:

```
   Timestamp                | CallID      | NextCallID  | Type
    ------------------------|-------------|-------------|-----
    2017-07-26 07:08:32.000 | 37461343    | 37565836    | M
    2017-07-26 07:31:06.000 | 37565804    | 37565938    | M
    2017-07-26 07:35:23.000 | 37565836    | 37565909    | S
    2017-07-26 07:42:23.000 | 37565909    | NULL        | E
    2017-07-26 07:45:04.000 | 37565938    | 37566044    | S
    2017-07-26 07:52:59.000 | 37566044    | NULL        | E
    2017-07-26 18:14:26.000 | 37565461    | 37565909    | M
    2017-07-26 18:24:48.000 | 37565804    | NULL        | M
    2017-07-26 18:26:11.000 | 37565836    | NULL        | M
    2017-07-26 18:29:23.000 | 37565909    | 37566044    | S
    2017-07-26 18:30:06.000 | 37565938    | NULL        | M
    2017-07-26 18:33:11.000 | 37566044    | NULL        | E
```

Output (Using CTE query):

```
   Timestamp                | MasterCallID| CallID      | NextCallID    | Type
    ------------------------|-------------|-------------|---------------|-------
    2017-07-26 07:08:32.000 | 37461343    | 37461343    | 37565836      | M
    2017-07-26 07:31:06.000 | 37565804    | 37565804    | 37565938      | M
    2017-07-26 07:35:23.000 | 37461343    | 37565836    | 37565909      | S
    2017-07-26 07:42:23.000 | 37461343    | 37565909    | NULL          | E
    2017-07-26 07:42:23.000 | 37565461    | 37565909    | NULL          | E
    2017-07-26 07:45:04.000 | 37565804    | 37565938    | 37566044      | S
    2017-07-26 07:52:59.000 | 37461343    | 37566044    | NULL          | E
    2017-07-26 07:52:59.000 | 37565461    | 37566044    | NULL          | E
    2017-07-26 07:52:59.000 | 37565804    | 37566044    | NULL          | E
    2017-07-26 18:14:26.000 | 37565461    | 37565461    | 37565909      | M
    2017-07-26 18:24:48.000 | 37565804    | 37565804    | NULL          | M
    2017-07-26 18:26:11.000 | 37565836    | 37565836    | NULL          | M
    2017-07-26 18:29:23.000 | 37461343    | 37565909    | 37566044      | S
    2017-07-26 18:29:23.000 | 37565461    | 37565909    | 37566044      | S
    2017-07-26 18:30:06.000 | 37565938    | 37565938    | NULL          | M
    2017-07-26 18:33:11.000 | 37461343    | 37566044    | NULL          | E
    2017-07-26 18:33:11.000 | 37565461    | 37566044    | NULL          | E
    2017-07-26 18:33:11.000 | 37565804    | 37566044    | NULL          | E
```

Desired Output:

```
   Timestamp                | MasterCallID| CallID      | NextCallID    | Type
    ------------------------|-------------|-------------|---------------|-------
    2017-07-26 07:08:32.000 | 37461343    | 37461343    | 37565836      | M
    2017-07-26 07:35:23.000 | 37461343    | 37565836    | 37565909      | S
    2017-07-26 07:42:23.000 | 37461343    | 37565909    | NULL          | E
    2017-07-26 07:31:06.000 | 37565804    | 37565804    | 37565938      | M
    2017-07-26 07:45:04.000 | 37565804    | 37565938    | 37566044      | S
    2017-07-26 07:52:59.000 | 37565804    | 37566044    | NULL          | E
    2017-07-26 18:14:26.000 | 37565461    | 37565461    | 37565909      | M
    2017-07-26 18:29:23.000 | 37565461    | 37565909    | 37566044      | S
    2017-07-26 18:33:11.000 | 37565461    | 37566044    | NULL          | E
    2017-07-26 18:26:11.000 | 37565836    | 37565836    | NULL          | M
```

Would greatly appreciate your assistance.

Regards

Comment: it's not "The proposed solutions does not work with the following scenario".  You changed the original scenario.  So, I think you should vote the answer if it's correspond to your original query.  Then, we can try to help you for this new request.

Comment: Pls read introduction to S.O. and learn to format text.  Then add a brief description of what you asked in your "new" question and pls show your effort (in this case, what have you tried to do to solve your new request starting from the query in answer?)

Comment: I'm working on it, but it's not very easy (at moment at least it seems so ...)

Comment: Tricky indeed. I think I'm on to something, but still working out the logic. Thanks for your efforts

Comment: I'm trying to solve it in the recursive part.  An easier solution (but I don't like it very much) could be in the final part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading better your requirements, I think you have to use a recursive query (CTE).  In the recursive part it extracts all the hierarchies.  I track the Master call in the last column (M2).

This query is not based on time order of calls as my former answer.  It works using only CallID and NextCallID, so you can have hierarchy of calls using same time too.

```
;WITH A AS (SELECT Timestamp,CallID,NextCallID,Type, CallID AS MasterCallID
            FROM CALLS WHERE TYPE='M'
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT B.Timestamp,B.CallID,B.NextCallID,B.Type, A.MasterCallID
            FROM CALLS B 
            INNER JOIN A ON A.NEXTCALLID=B.CALLID
            WHERE B.TYPE<>'M')
SELECT  Timestamp
        , MasterCallID  
        , CallID
        , NextCallID
        , CASE Type WHEN 'M' Then 'Master' WHEN 'S' THEN 'Sub/Transfer' WHEN 'E' THEN 'End Call' ELSE '' END AS Type
FROM A 
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------+------------+----------+------------+--------------+
|        Timestamp        | MASTERCALL |  CallID  | NextCallID |     Type     |
+-------------------------+------------+----------+------------+--------------+
| 2017-07-26 14:37:24.000 |   37468024 | 37468024 | 37594497   | Master       |
| 2017-07-26 14:51:27.000 |   37468024 | 37594497 | 37595080   | Sub/Transfer |
| 2017-07-26 14:59:30.000 |   37468024 | 37595080 | 37512345   | Sub/Transfer |
| 2017-07-26 14:59:59.000 |   37468024 | 37512345 | NULL       | End Call     |
| 2017-07-26 18:59:59.000 |   37594497 | 37594497 | NULL       | Master       |
+-------------------------+------------+----------+------------+--------------+
```

**New version after question edit (above query can create wrong "link" call-mastercall):**

```
; WITH A AS (SELECT Timestamp,CallID,NextCallID,Type, CallID AS MasterCallID, Timestamp AS TIMEMASTER 
            FROM CALLS WHERE TYPE='M'
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT B.Timestamp,B.CallID,B.NextCallID,B.Type, A.MasterCallID, A.TIMEMASTER 
            FROM CALLS B 
            INNER JOIN A ON B.CALLID=A.NEXTCALLID AND B.TIMESTAMP>A.TIMESTAMP           
            WHERE B.TYPE<>'M')
SELECT  A.Timestamp
        , A.MasterCallID  
        , A.CallID
        , A.NextCallID
        , CASE A.Type WHEN 'M' Then 'Master' WHEN 'S' THEN 'Sub/Transfer' WHEN 'E' THEN 'End Call' ELSE '' END AS Type
FROM A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT TIMESTAMP, CALLID, MAX(TIMEMASTER) MAXTIMEM FROM A GROUP BY TIMESTAMP, CALLID) C ON A.TIMESTAMP=C.TIMESTAMP AND A.CALLID=C.CALLID AND A.TIMEMASTER = C.MAXTIMEM
ORDER BY TIMEMASTER, TIMESTAMP
;
```

Output with new sample data:

```
Timestamp                MasterCallID  CallID        NextCallID    Type
------------------------ ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------
2017-07-26 07:08:32.000  37461343      37461343      37565836      Master
2017-07-26 07:35:23.000  37461343      37565836      37565909      Sub/Transfer
2017-07-26 07:42:23.000  37461343      37565909      NULL          End Call
2017-07-26 07:31:06.000  37565804      37565804      37565938      Master
2017-07-26 07:45:04.000  37565804      37565938      37566044      Sub/Transfer
2017-07-26 07:52:59.000  37565804      37566044      NULL          End Call
2017-07-26 18:14:26.000  37565461      37565461      37565909      Master
2017-07-26 18:29:23.000  37565461      37565909      37566044      Sub/Transfer
2017-07-26 18:33:11.000  37565461      37566044      NULL          End Call
2017-07-26 18:24:48.000  37565804      37565804      NULL          Master
2017-07-26 18:26:11.000  37565836      37565836      NULL          Master
2017-07-26 18:30:06.000  37565938      37565938      NULL          Master
```

Comment: Thanks etsa, I'll give it a go with more permutations and let you know if it works.

Comment: @Wazimh  In a few minutes I'll post another query.  I think this latter will fit best your requirements.

Comment: Thanks etsa, your CTE query worked! I actually had something similar, but my join on the recursive query to the anchor was wrong (face palm). Thanks again.

Comment: unfortunately I found a scenario where the CTE query above does not help. Please see amendment to my question above. Appreciate it your assistance.

Comment: @Wazimh: I don't understand where it doesn't respect your question

Comment: Apologies for that, the question has been amended now. Please check the "Amendment:" section of my question above. Thanks

Comment: that's my bad, new to the site and tight deadline. Still no excuse and not like me. Formatted correctly now.

Comment: It's basically same question, it's just that in the examples I've come across now, the CallID's are repeated more often. I.e. from being Master to a Sub and back to Master, etc. Will Amend original question and include the steps I've taken.

Comment: @Wazimh new query added.  Why did you remove from your output master calls 37565804  and 37565938 (present in your sample data)?

Comment: Thanks @etsa! The new query works with all scenarios thrown at it so far on the entire dataset. As for excluding 37565804 and 37565938, looks like I skipped it when copying from excel. How do I rate you further over and above marking the answer as correct? :-)

Comment: Definitely. Sharing is Caring :-)... Thanks again and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `grouping` the elements in your initial query using `SUM` with `OVER`:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [Timestamp] DATETIME2
   ,[CallID] BIGINT
   ,[NextCallID] BIGINT
   ,[Type] CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Timestamp], [CallID], [NextCallID], [Type])
VALUES ('2017-07-26 14:37:24.000', 37468024, 37594497, 'M')
      ,('2017-07-26 14:51:27.000', 37594497, 37595080, 'S')
      ,('2017-07-26 14:59:30.000', 37595080, 37512345, 'S')
      ,('2017-07-26 14:59:59.000', 37512345, NULL, 'E')
      ,('2017-07-26 18:59:59.000', 37594497, NULL, 'M');

SELECT *
      ,SUM(IIF([Type] = 'M', 1, 0)) OVER (ORDER BY [Timestamp] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS [Group]
FROM @DataSource
ORDER BY [Timestamp] ASC;
```

[image]

Knowing the group of each call we need only to found `CallID`, where `Type` is `M` for each group:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,SUM(IIF([Type] = 'M', 1, 0)) OVER (ORDER BY [Timestamp] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS [Group]
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT *
      ,MAX(IIF([Type] = 'M', [CallID], NULL)) OVER (PARTITION BY [Group])
FROM DataSource
ORDER BY [Timestamp] ASC;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks gotqn, your solution works with this supplied dataset too. My only concern is grouping by timeStamp only when using much larger datasets in production. Will test this and provide feedback.

Comment: your query stopped working with a couple of scenarios. Please see amendment to my question above. Appreciate it.